# Shared session between laravel and vue apps

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-session

I have 3 apps and those 2 are laravel apps and 1 is vuejs

I've tried setting up session to store session data in to the database so that I can have a shared sessions between my apps.

Things work between laravel apps, however, I have trouble when it comes to my vuejs app.

Btw, in order to proceed to any of my vue routes, I have to check first if token exists and is correct.

But since I am using laravel sessions now, I guess I need to check for cookie session id now?

and if so, where do I set the cookie session id?

Answer (score 0):

Better use Laravel passport (OAuth) as a token generation for you Vue application.